SQLDatabaseChain result shows "Answer" value incorrectly?
I am looking for help regarding an issue with my SQLDatabasechain invoke() results.
Here is my langchain code - I created a db_chain with my llm (model) and db (MySQL database) using SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm method  - then I executed db_chain.invoke() passing  my database query as a parameter.  The query is written in human-readable format instead of an SQL statement, because the llm can take care of it.  I passed the verbose=True parameter in the invoke method so it will produce the intermediate log results that I can validate.
from langchain_experimental.sql import SQLDatabaseChain

# pass the verbose=True to check the internals 
db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm, db, verbose=True) # , return_direct = True)
qns1 = db_chain.invoke("How many t-shirts do we have left for nike in extra small size and red color?")

Below is the verbose result of the db_chain.invoke():

Everything look ok - the SQLQuery shows 59 which is the expected count from the query - however, I am expecting the "Answer" statement to show 59 - but instead it is showing the Question: label  followed by  the value of the generated SQL query instead.
What am I missing???

You should use verbose=False.

@Lewis I tried again and this time I updated the from_llm method by replacing "verbose=True" with "return_direct=True "as follows: db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm, db, return_direct=True).     Now I am seeing this output {'query': 'How many t-shirts do we have left for nike in extra small size and red color?', 'result': '[(59,)]'} . However I don't understand why 'result' is showing [(59,)] instead of plain 59. the langchain codebase should have unpacked the value for us.
